# Managing Database Connections in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and I have written a number of Controller classes that have this ivar:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

I have also read that each request creates a new instance of the Controller.

I am concerned about database connection churn.

Should I be using a single global connection object instead? Or is there connection pooling happening behind the scenes and I shouldn't worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Entity Framework ORM tool, [it is not recommended to use `DbContext` as a singleton instance](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/dont-use-singleton-datacontexts-entity.html), so, avoid to keep it on the global.asax. A good pratice is to use it with the pattern `Unit of Work`. [Read this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx).

[In this another article](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/) you can see sample pros and cons about how to keep an instance of DbContext.